# Adding dynamic HTTP Headers to WS Outbound Gateway

Tags: java, web-services, spring-integration, spring-ws

I would like to enrich my HTTP/SOAP request (send with WS Outbound Gateway) with some custom HTTP Headers depending on what actually `Message` contains, i.e.

- add Basic Authentication per request where credentials depend on some `Message.headers`
- add custom HTTP header only if specific `Message.headers` exists

I considered the following solutions:

1. Implementing custom `ClientInterceptor` - but there is no access to
   Message.header at this point
2. Implementing custom `SoapHeaderMapper` - there is access to `Message.header` but I do not like this idea as it is rather meant
   to operate on SOAP envelope not on connection/request level.
3. Implementing custom `WebServiceMessageCallback` - no access to Message at this point.

Also, in context of Authentication, all above solutions rely on adding necessary HTTP Authentication headers on our own, while I would like to do it in more correct way (at least in my opinion) and properly configure `HttpClient`.

So at this point I finished with custom `HttpComponentsMessageSender` that sets up `HttpClientContext` per each request. The problem is that again there is no access to `Mesage.headers` so I finished with some combination of `ServiceActivator` with SPEL and `ThreadLocal` as presented below.

Generally it works but... is there any other more correct path to go?

```
<int:service-activator expression="@basicAuthenticationMessageSender.setBasicAuth(#root, headers.username, headers.pass)" />


public class BasicAuthenticationMessageSender extends HttpComponentsMessageSender {

private static ThreadLocal<HttpClientContext> httpClientContextLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

@Override
protected HttpContext createContext(URI uri) {
    HttpClientContext httpClientContext = httpClientContextLocal.get();

    // This part makes authentication preemptive:
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getScheme());
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());
    httpClientContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

    return httpClientContext;
}

public GenericMessage setBasicAuth(GenericMessage message, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    final HttpClientContext httpClientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    httpClientContext.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

    httpClientContextLocal.set(httpClientContext);
    return message;
}
}
```

Spring Integration 4.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Since Spring Integration WS support is fully based on the Spring WS project, there is nothing more we can in SI what the SWS provides for us.

Anyway you can inject `WebServiceMessageCallback` into the `AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway` and there get access to the `ThreadLocal` variable for the `Message` populated there before calling this WS Gateway.

There in the `WebServiceMessageCallback` you should get access to the:

```
TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();

connection.getConnection().addRequestProperty("hea derParameter", "headerValue");
```

The same `TransportContext` you can access from the custom `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` though and there already even without any `ThreadLocal`:

```
@Override
protected void populateUserDefinedHeader(String headerName, Object headerValue, SoapMessage target) {
    super.populateUserDefinedHeader(headerName, headerValue, target);

    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
    HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();

    connection.getConnection().addRequestProperty(headerName, headerValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. So I will continue with extending `HttpComponentsMessageSender` for Authentication. Other custom HTTP Headers with custom `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` as it has access to `Message.headers`.